# how to check if number input is empty, using a if statement

Tags: python

The title says it all. I tried doing this:

```
import random

speed = float(input("Which was the speed of the vehicle in that moment? "))

trafficTicket = 0

if speed == "": 

    print("The speed was not informed. ")

    randomNumber = random.randint(1, 120)

    RandomTrafficTicketValue = randomNumber * 7

    print(f"O value of the traffic ticket in this situation is going to be {RandomTrafficTicketValue} dollars. ")

if speed < 30:

    print("The vehicle's speed is very low, tell the driver to change hands. ")

if speed > 90:

    trafficTicketValue = speed - 90

    print(f"Due to speed above the permitted speed, the driver must receive a trafficTicket worth {trafficTicketValue * 7} dollars. ")
```

but got this error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: ''
```

Any way to go around it, so I can make an if statement when the user doesn't type anything?

I tried finding a solution based on what I needed but only found a question involving Python made in 2010, and that isn't especially what I'm trying to find.

Comment: Don't use `float()` until after you check if it's empty or not.

Comment: i provided more code so the question can be more crearly to be answered, but also tried what you suggested, like this: https://imgur.com/a/nBdcR4g but got the same error

Comment: @jordanm exactly. @jorgityo, don't use ```float()``` when you are checking emptiness. After that, use error handling to determine whether it is a float, then proceed to convert it to a float.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply handle the exception. This will also handle the situation where the input is not blank but also can't be converted to a float.

```
try:
    speed = float(input("Which was the speed of the vehicle in that moment? "))
    if speed < 30:
        print("The vehicle's speed is very low, tell the driver to change hands. ")
    if speed > 90:
        trafficTicketValue = speed - 90
        print(f"Due to speed above the permitted speed, the driver must receive a trafficTicket worth {trafficTicketValue * 7} dollars. ")
except ValueError:
    print("The speed was not informed. ")
    randomNumber = random.randint(1, 120)
    RandomTrafficTicketValue = randomNumber * 7
    print(f"O value of the traffic ticket in this situation is going to be {RandomTrafficTicketValue} dollars. ")
```

Answer (score 1):

Accept the input as a plain string and check if it is empty **before** you call `float()`:

```
speed = input("what was your speed? ")

# if they actually typed something, convert it to a float
if speed:
    speed = float(speed)

    # now handle the various speed values

else:
    print("You did not enter anything")
```

Comment: Might be worth trimming whitespace to ensure the user didn't enter `" "`.

Comment: It worked just in the way that i wanted, thank you! Also didnt know that Python dont required a condition in the if statement, always good to learn more.

Comment: The `if` (or `elif`) requires an expression that can be evaluated to a truth-y value. In this case, `speed` is false if it's an empty string, and true otherwise.